# Preventing linewrap when using pexpect / bash

Tags: python, bash, terminal, tty, pexpect

When executing the following script (simplified example):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
spawn = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')
with open('/tmp/logfile.log', 'w') as f:
    spawn.logfile_read = f
    spawn.sendline('echo "Hello I am a really long command, in fact I am 100 characters long! Potato Potato Potato....."')
    spawn.sendline('exit')
    spawn.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

I have trouble with line wrapping causing `^M` characters appearing in the log.  The pexpect logfile now literally looks like this:

```bash
bash-3.2$ echo "Hello I am a really long command, in fact I am 100 characters lo ^Mng! Potato Potato Potato....."
Hello I am a really long command, in fact I am 100 characters long! Potato Potato Potato.....
bash-3.2$ exit
exit
```

After 80 characters the line is wrapped by a carriage return, and I don't want that.  I've tried a lot of different things to disable line-wrapping (using `tput rmam`, calling `stty columns 1000` beforehand, using `spawn.setwinsize(1000, 1000)`, setting `os.environ['COLUMNS'] = "1000"`, passing various args to /bin/bash..) and I can't seem to find the right trick.

How can the line wrapping be disabled in this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured this out. What pointed me in the right direction was when I remembered that the `echo` command is internal to bash. Changing the command to /bin/echo completely changed the behavior. This was only part of the solution.

Seeing that it appears that bash itself is the problem I looked through the man page to see what the cause may be. Then it hit me! Bash uses readline support and sure enough disabling it fixes your problem regardless of using /bin/echo or the internal echo command.

Just change your spawn line to `spawn = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash --noediting')`.

Comment: I noticed that there is an interaction with shell startups.  For example, if I include --norc in the bash line, simply adding setwinsize is *not* enough.  Simply adding setwinsize might not be reliable in batch environments.

Comment: Your code does not work for me ... indeed `spawn.setwinsize(1000, 1000)` was one of the things I've already mentioned trying in my original question.

Comment: There must be something different about your execution environment. setwinsize utilizes signaling to get the expected results. Where are you running your script from?

Comment: I'm just executing it from bash

Comment: What terminal are you using? I have a feeling that the SIGWINCH isn't getting to your shell. Also, have you tried adding `spawn.sendline('export COLUMNS=1000')`. I know some applications specifically look for that.

Comment: I'm using gnome-terminal on Ubuntu

Comment: I've totally changed my answer now. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I was having this same issue. Using `setwinsize(1000,1000)` worked for me.

```
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh %s@%s' % (user, host))
child.setwinsize(1000,1000)
```